# How to determine a new plugin installation vs a version upgrade in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I need to determine when the plugin is first installed. I also need this to be backward compatible for existing users (to not false positive identify existing plugins as new installations):

In the VSCode **extension** documentation, I found this snippet but I don't understand what "application" means in this context:

[link](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#env)

```
isNewAppInstall: boolean

Indicates that this is a fresh install of the application. true if within the first day of installation otherwise false.
```

[image]
Does "application" in this documentation mean "VSCode was installed today", or is the plugin the "application".

I would assume not many users install plugins on the same day they installed vscode - but I can't test this quickly to be sure.

Comment: release a version that writes a date to the persistent/Memento storage of the extension, a date a few days ago. This will be done by existing users. Wait a few days. Then release a version that checks if the date in the persistent storage is present, if not a new user. Yes it will give a few false positive and false negative